# Jquery Autocomplete Increase Number of Items to display

Tags: jquery, caching, autocomplete

I have being using jquery autocomplete. By default it is showing 10 items in the dropdown, i want to increase its number to 20 or customise it according to requirement. i have tried many ways of cache length but none of them is working. pls suggest a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example helps, [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/) you can change the max items which is being shown. Hope it helps you